# SQL : update table from another grouped table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables :

**Product (P1)**

```
id,   
amount
```

**Price (P2)**

```
id  
productId  
calibre  
amount
```

I want to update P1 `amount` column so that it is equal to the sum of P2  `amount` column per `productId`.

For example, from

**P1**

```
'apple',0  
'orange,0
```

**P2**

```
'apple', 'A', 5  
'apple', 'B', 6  
'orange' 'AA',1  
'orange' 'BBB', 3  
'orange', 'CCC', 4
```

After update, P1 is like :

```
'apple', 11  
'orange', 8
```

I can't find the SQL syntax to achieve this.

If someone knows...

Thank you.

Comment: Please clean up your table definitions as `P2` is missing data.  Also please label which database you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Next time you post please update your tags appropriately.  Giving the correct tags is especially important with SQL questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't tag your DBMS, I think this will be correct for most DBMS's :

```
UPDATE P1
SET p1.amount = (SELECT sum(p2.amount) FROM P2
                 WHERE p1.productID = p2.productID)
```

If p1 can have products that won't appear in p2, the you should use nvl functions - every dbms can have different functions to deal with nulls - coalesce,nvl ETC... Then change the sum(p2.amount) to:

```
COALESCE(sum(p2.amount),0)
NVL(sum(p2.amount),0)
```

Chose which one that suits you

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do your `UPDATE` query is to do an `INNER JOIN` of `P1` with a temporary table containing the sums of `P2`:

**MySQL:**

```
UPDATE P1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT productId, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM P2
    GROUP BY productId
) t
    ON P1.id = t.productId
SET P1.amount = t.amount
```

**SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE P1
SET P1.amount = t.amount
FROM P1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT productId, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM P2
    GROUP BY productId
) t
    ON P1.id = t.productId
```

I'm hoping that your database is either MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: @sagi I like your answer because it is ANSI-92 compliant, but doing a join should outperform a correlated subquery.  So in this case, I might go for the join.

Comment: I agree that while knowing the DBMS you can come out with a better solution(like yours) But at the time we didn't